# How do I change the default stat in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know how to change the default colour in bar charts blue

```
update_geom_defaults("bar", list(fill = "blue"))
```

but how do I change the stat component. I tried

```
update_geom_defaults("bar", list(stat = "identity"))
```

but after I attempt a `ggplot() + geom_bar(...)` I get the error message `Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin"`. How do I actually change the defaults?

I noticed that

```
> update_geom_defaults
function (geom, new) 
{
    g <- Geom$find(geom)
    old <- g$default_aes()
    aes <- defaults(new, old)
    g$default_aes <- eval(substitute(function(.) aes, list(aes = aes)))
}
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

seems to only apply the update to aesthetics.

Answer (score 1):

`update_geom_defaults` and `update_stat_defaults` are functions to change the default aesthetic mapping. 
IFIIK, There is no function to change the default stats, but you can easily do the job by, e.g.,

```
geom_bar_i <- function(...) geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = am, y = vs)) + geom_bar_i()
```